# Positioning network probes to span the globe

Tags: geolocation, ip, p2p

I'm trying to connect to a given number of peers in a P2P network and I'd like to have them span the globe as good as possible (have them as far away from each other as possible). Since I gradually connect to them one after another I will discover better peers one after another and discard (or disconnect) from peers that drop out of my top list. Problem is that I'm stuck defining a metric that tells me how "good" a peer is. I will be using a geo ip database to map ips to geo coordinates but I just can't find a good metric to apply.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should not think of geography but in network topology. For every new peer you should do `traceroute` and `ping` so you know how the good the connectivity is. Store this and do cost-calculation. Most simply in just adding up the latency. Bandwidth and latency are more important. If you are concerned with the local laws where the specific peer is located you could start think in geography.

Comment: A graph-database is very suitable eg finding the node with most edges.

Comment: Problem is that the network runs a single client, thus having a fixed degree (number of connections). Traceroute and pings are not really nice because they cause additional traffic and only tell me anything from my route to the nodes but nothing about how well the nodes are connected with each other. I know my global distribution is based on the assumption that latency and loss is mainly due to sheer distance between the nodes but it's the best option I have for now.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder, are you able to get your users to set a location in their UI? That might be a better measure of geographical spread than ping times. That said, for a variety of complicated reasons - as I'm sure you know - two nodes 500 miles apart may have better speed and latency measurements than two nodes 250 miles apart. So it depends whether you care about location or performance :)